# Sagemaker Model Explainability Monitoring: model_explainability_monitor.suggest_baseline() returned all zero SHAP values

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am writing code for model monitoring using Sagemaker API. After running Sagemaker's Model Explainability Monitor and running the suggest baseline function, I received an output with all zero SHAP values, which is strange. What could possibly cause this?

Model Explainability Monitor:

```
model_explainability_monitor = ModelExplainabilityMonitor(
    max_runtime_in_seconds=18000,
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    volume_size_in_gb=20,
)
```

SHAP Baseline generated from dataset.mean()

```
[[39.43361724652327, 1192.4743275107069, 2.726865887108416, 3.0728068909099657, 2.7648813820316636, 2.9901352196718154, 3.2045618593907896, 3.249025552187094, 3.4428083345363554, 3.367066069967759, 3.383571531687599, 3.3636013666329823, 3.6376497762379096, 3.2981569703094173, 3.6430393147586737, 3.2894952119724747, 14.817958712285261, 15.293686039776018, 0.5047399066454935, 0.49526009335450655, 0.8224339540926808, 0.1775660459073192, 0.6872624031567297, 0.3127375968432703, 0.47548241181848805, 0.45382801597613204, 0.07068957220537991]]
```

SHAP Config

```
shap_config = SHAPConfig(
    agg_method='mean_abs',
    baseline=shap_baseline,
    num_samples=100,
    save_local_shap_values=False,
)
```

Model Config

```
model_config = ModelConfig(
    accept_type=dataset_type,
    content_type=dataset_type,
    instance_count=endpoint_instance_count,
    instance_type=endpoint_instance_type,
    model_name=model_name
)
```

Model Explainability Monitor.suggest_baseline():

```
model_explainability_monitor.suggest_baseline(
    data_config=model_explainability_data_config,
    explainability_config=shap_config,
    job_name=job_name,
    logs=True,
    model_config=model_config,
    wait=True,
)
```

Output:

```
0% (0 of 20781) |                      | Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 ETA:  --:--:--
  0% (56 of 20781) |                     | Elapsed Time: 0:00:30 ETA:   3:06:13
  0% (119 of 20781) |                    | Elapsed Time: 0:01:00 ETA:   2:46:00
  0% (187 of 20781) |                    | Elapsed Time: 0:01:30 ETA:   2:32:47
  1% (249 of 20781) |                    | Elapsed Time: 0:02:00 ETA:   2:45:48
                               ---
100% (20781 of 20781) |##################| Elapsed Time: 2:50:38 Time:  2:50:38

2023-03-27 20:29:06,177 getting explanations took 10246.71 seconds.
2023-03-27 20:29:06,178 ===================================================
2023-03-27 20:29:06,179 Falling back to generic labels: label0, label1, ...
2023-03-27 20:29:08,604 converting explanations to tabular took 2.43 seconds.
2023-03-27 20:29:08,604 ===================================================
2023-03-27 20:29:08,604 Local explanations weren't saved, 'methods.shap.save_local_shap_values' is not enabled
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3430: FutureWarning: In a future version, DataFrame.mean(axis=None) will return a scalar mean over the entire DataFrame. To retain the old behavior, use 'frame.mean(axis=0)' or just 'frame.mean()'
  return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
2023-03-27 20:29:08,611 aggregating local explanations took 0.01 seconds.
2023-03-27 20:29:08,611 ===================================================
2023-03-27 20:29:08,612 Shap analysis finished.
2023-03-27 20:29:08,614 Calculated global analysis with predictor
2023-03-27 20:29:08,614 Stop using endpoint: sm-clarify-AirlineSatisfactionOHE1-1679937856-8834
2023-03-27 20:29:08,614 Deleting endpoint configuration with name: sm-clarify-config-1679937855-1a90
2023-03-27 20:29:08,830 Deleting endpoint with name: sm-clarify-AirlineSatisfactionOHE1-1679937856-8834
2023-03-27 20:29:09,005 Model endpoint delivered 2.02775 requests per second and a total of 20783 requests over 10249 seconds
2023-03-27 20:29:09,005 Calculated global analysis without predictor
2023-03-27 20:29:09,278 Local shap values path does not exist.
2023-03-27 20:29:09,493 Unable to display local shap values, local shap values not found
2023-03-27 20:29:09,622 Stop using endpoint: None
2023-03-27 20:29:09,815 Unable to display local shap values, local shap values not found
2023-03-27 20:29:09,826 ['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'html', '--output', '/opt/ml/processing/output/report.html', '/opt/ml/processing/output/report.ipynb', '--template', 'sagemaker-xai']
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook /opt/ml/processing/output/report.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Writing 429574 bytes to /opt/ml/processing/output/report.html
2023-03-27 20:29:10,840 ['wkhtmltopdf', '-q', '--enable-local-file-access', '/opt/ml/processing/output/report.html', '/opt/ml/processing/output/report.pdf']
2023-03-27 20:29:11,501 Collected analyses: 
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "explanations": {
        "kernel_shap": {
            "label0": {
                "global_shap_values": {
                    "Age": 0.0,
                    "Flight Distance": 0.0,
                    "Inflight wifi service": 0.0,
                    "Departure/Arrival time convenient": 0.0,
                    "Ease of Online booking": 0.0,
                    "Gate location": 0.0,
                    "Food and drink": 0.0,
                    "Online boarding": 0.0,
                    "Seat comfort": 0.0,
                    "Inflight entertainment": 0.0,
                    "On-board service": 0.0,
                    "Leg room service": 0.0,
                    "Baggage handling": 0.0,
                    "Checkin service": 0.0,
                    "Inflight service": 0.0,
                    "Cleanliness": 0.0,
                    "Departure Delay in Minutes": 0.0,
                    "Arrival Delay in Minutes": 0.0,
                    "Gender_Female": 0.0,
                    "Gender_Male": 0.0,
                    "Customer Type_Loyal Customer": 0.0,
                    "Customer Type_disloyal Customer": 0.0,
                    "Type of Travel_Business travel": 0.0,
                    "Type of Travel_Personal Travel": 0.0,
                    "Class_Business": 0.0,
                    "Class_Eco": 0.0,
                    "Class_Eco Plus": 0.0
                },
                "expected_value": 1.0
            },
            "label1": {
                "global_shap_values": {
                    "Age": 0.0,
                    "Flight Distance": 0.0,
                    "Inflight wifi service": 0.0,
                    "Departure/Arrival time convenient": 0.0,
                    "Ease of Online booking": 0.0,
                    "Gate location": 0.0,
                    "Food and drink": 0.0,
                    "Online boarding": 0.0,
                    "Seat comfort": 0.0,
                    "Inflight entertainment": 0.0,
                    "On-board service": 0.0,
                    "Leg room service": 0.0,
                    "Baggage handling": 0.0,
                    "Checkin service": 0.0,
                    "Inflight service": 0.0,
                    "Cleanliness": 0.0,
                    "Departure Delay in Minutes": 0.0,
                    "Arrival Delay in Minutes": 0.0,
                    "Gender_Female": 0.0,
                    "Gender_Male": 0.0,
                    "Customer Type_Loyal Customer": 0.0,
                    "Customer Type_disloyal Customer": 0.0,
                    "Type of Travel_Business travel": 0.0,
                    "Type of Travel_Personal Travel": 0.0,
                    "Class_Business": 0.0,
                    "Class_Eco": 0.0,
                    "Class_Eco Plus": 0.0
                },
                "expected_value": 0.0
            }
        }
    }
}
2023-03-27 20:29:11,502 exit_message: Completed: SageMaker XAI Analyzer ran successfully
--------------!
```

Dataset Used: Airline Passenger Satisfaction from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/teejmahal20/airline-passenger-satisfaction?resource=download

I'm not sure why the baseline is all zeros.